# Indecomposable objects in iterated functor categories

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, abelian-categories, modular-representation-theory

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a DVR with a uniformizer $\pi$ and a finite quotient field $\mathbb{F}_q=\mathcal{O}/\pi$. Write $\mathcal{O}_r = \mathcal{O}/(\pi^r)$. Fix now an integer $r\geq 2$. We define inductively the following categories:
$\mathcal{C}_1 = \mathcal{O}_r-mod$, the category of left $\mathcal{O}_r$-modules, and $$\mathcal{C}_{n+1} = Fun_{\mathcal{O}_r}(\mathcal{C}_n,\mathcal{O}_r-mod),$$
the category of all $\mathcal{O}_r$-additive functors from $\mathcal{C}_n$ to $\mathcal{O}_r-mod$ (we consider all additive functors, not necessarily exact ones).

**Question**: Is it true that for every $n$, the category $\mathcal{C}_n$ has only finitely many isomorphism classes of indecomposable objects? Is it true that for every indecomposable object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}_n$ it holds that $\text{End}_{\mathcal{C}_n}(X)\cong \mathcal{O}_a$ for some $a\leq r$? Is there a known classification of the indecomposable objects in $\mathcal{C}_n$?